# odoo 14: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'categry_id.base_category'

Tags: python, odoo, valueerror

when click on Many2one brand_id field in view (xml), it throwing error.
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'categry_id.base_category'

added a computed field *base_category* in **product.category** which type is *Integer*, with help of **@SDBot** here.
first in the domain of *brand_id* i didn't used int() but when searched for error above, i tried to use int('categry_id.base_category') but still getting same error.

below are 2 models, first in which i created base_category value -thanks to @SDBot-, (it is created from a Char type field and storing value in Integer type field and *even after update values manually through psql the error is same*)
second is where i am getting error in the domain filter.

please help to solve the problem.

```
class ProductCateg(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.category'

    level = fields.Integer(string='Level', compute='_compute_level', store=True)
    base_category = fields.Integer('Base Cat', compute='_compute_basecat', store=True)

    @api.depends('parent_id')
    def _compute_level(self):
        for record in self:
            record.level = (record.parent_id.level or 0) + 1

    @api.depends('parent_id')
    def _compute_basecat(self):
        for rec in self:
            split_str = (rec.parent_path or '').split('/')
            rec.base_category = int(split_str[1]) if len(split_str) > 1 else ''


class OrderItems(models.Model):
    _name = 'tests.orderitems'
    _description = "Tests Order Items"

    store_id = fields.Many2one('tests.stores', string="Store", ondelete='cascade')
    order_id = fields.Many2one('tests.testsorders')
    categry_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Category",
                                 domain="[['complete_name', 'not like', '%Brands%']]")
    items_id = fields.Many2one('tests.storeitems', string="Item",
                               domain="[['categs_id', '=', categry_id]]")
    brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Brand",
                               domain=[('base_category', '=', int('categry_id.base_category')),('complete_name', 'like', '%Brands%')])
```

Comment: You have an issue in the field 'brand_id' with adding the domain. remove the first domain and check again.

Comment: thanks, but this is required to filter records in Many2one brand_id field here. is there any other solution? what is the issue in field brand_id?

Comment: tell me is this the same issue?  and yes you can compare the value like this - ('base_category', '=', categry_id.base_category). where this is already 'categry_id' field to use.

Comment: when remove single quotes as instructed, it is now showing error at restart of odoo server AttributeError: 'Many2one' object has no attribute 'base_category'. now i do not have ui in browser.

Comment: @Dipen Shah it seems a bug... ? or my mistake / misunderstanding ?

Comment: Could you please add example "parent_path" values?

Comment: @CZoellner parent path from model product_category:  1/14/27/53/

Comment: it is not the bug. first I have to check if do not add the domain if it is working or not? if yes then we only have to do work on the domain which you check for base_category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the value within the tests.orderitems first:

```
    categry_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Category",
                                 domain="[['complete_name', 'not like', '%Brands%']]")
    base_category = fields.Integer('Base Cat', related='categry_id.base_category')
    brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Brand",
                               domain="[('base_category', '=', base_category),('complete_name', 'like', '%Brands%')])"
```

Comment: hi @SDBots, thanks to come and again help me... it is working as i wants to, now i can restrict to show related Brands only :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help, also great job solving brand filtering issue!

Comment: with your help @SDBot, off course :)  after the idea failed adding 'level' i didn't disappoint but feel challange to have a solution and start thinking how it can be done and at last you did the job for me. be blessed :)

Answer (score 0):

The defaul value you put should be 0 not '' for an int.

```
rec.base_category = int(split_str[1]) if len(split_str) > 1 else ''
```

Comment: thanks, will check and confirm. i have to update all records or just null values?

Comment: now modified model and all values are updated manually as integer, still the same error. can't post screenshot in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

A field of type `Integer` is expecting an integer. So just give it an integer in your `else` part. Odoo is setting `0` as default and you can't set `None` in form of database `NULL`.

```py
rec.base_category = int(split_str[1]) if len(split_str) > 1 else 0
```

Comment: thanks, already done it in response of @lllrnr101 he point out me for this mistake.